# "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work..." when saving/deleting content

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a site where saving or deleting content frequently displays an error message "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work and then reload this page"

- It does not seem to matter what type of content.
- It happens on new content, as well as editing existing content.
- It doesn't matter how long the page is open before Save/Delete is clicked.
- There is only one person editing at a time.

Can someone suggest a way to track down this bug as it's proving difficult to find.

Comment: I have only seen this happen when I have had 2 browsers open on the same form then tried to save one.

Comment: This happens because a new session is created sometime when the form is being edited; so the edit becomes invalid as it is from previous session. Are you using authentication other than the default authentication provided by Drupal?

Comment: Can you paste your list of module?

Comment: Modules are: acl
advanced_forum
apply_for_role
backup_migrate
backup_migrate_files
better_exposed_filters
drupal
calendar
captcha
carousel
cf
chain_menu_access
ckeditor_link
config_perms
content_access
context
context_menu_block
ctools
date
enabled_modules
entity
features
feeds
field_collection
field_permissions
field_slideshow
file_entity
flood_control
forum_access
imce
imce_wysiwyg

Comment: job_scheduler
libraries
link
logintoboggan
login_destination
mail_edit
media
media_update
menu_block
references
panels
panels_breadcrumbs
pathauto
pathauto_persist
pathologic
rename_admin_paths
rules
scheduler
security_review
site_map
stringoverrides
subscriptions
superfish

Comment: @Rob Do you see multiple entries (for the same user) like `Session opened for USER` at `admin/reports/dblog`?

Comment: @Indrock I can only see one entry, for the main user, she logged in once this morning.  It's possible older entries have been truncated of course.  I asked and although she might have more than one browser open, only edits the page using a single browser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer provided by warwickshaw on D.O https://www.drupal.org/node/2241311#comment-8791165

> To fix the error message: 'The form has become outdated. ...' try
>   moving the 'drupal_private_key' in to the Drupal 7 settings.php file.
>
> The Issue See
>   https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_ge...
>   drupal_get_private_key() is not a safe function.
>
> When variable_get() doesn't return a $key (some outage, maybe a
>   memcached restarted) you suddenly and silently get assigned a new
>   drupal_get_private_key.
>
> If you are using multiple server Drupal system where each server has
>   it's own MySql database replicated from a Master DB, a Slave DB can
>   end up with it's own key (which Master doesn't see) and when the slave
>   gets it's key cached in memcached the fun begins.
>
> Mean while back in the D7 Admin, forms and menus that once worked
>   start failing!
>
> The Fix The only safe place in D7 whether using a single or
>   multi-server setup is to move 'drupal_private_key' value to the
>   settings.php file.
>
> Add $conf['drupal_private_key'] = '...';
>
> To get the value execute on the Staging server (MySql master) drush ev
>   'print drupal_get_private_key();' and assign the value above.
>
> You should have something like this (these are example values, don't
>   use) $drupal_hash_salt =
>   'j8lnCx-XF3gq_2NmnnHZ61Q3xlbKHFSzZ9EmUouPwKU';
>   $conf['drupal_private_key'] =
>   'Fnll-1ZETTb03CgO6PW4COWT7CjTBeRSAQzXqerq6FA';
>
> Check the hash_salt is behaving correctly (should match
>   $drupal_hash_salt) drush ev 'print drupal_get_hash_salt();'
>
> Copy these setting to all other servers in the same Drupal cluster.
>
> On Stage update 'drupal_private_key' row with value used in the
>   settings.php file. This will replicate and reset any MySql slaves out
>   of sync. update variable set value = '[drupal_private_key]' where name
>   = 'drupal_private_key';
>
> On Stage execute drush cc all
>
> Clear your browser cache.
>
> You are good to go!
>
> New D7 Projects When ever you create a new Drupal project make this
>   the first task after installation.
>
> Other Symptoms of the Same Bug Multiple Save, Cancel buttons appears
>   after clicking Save or Cancel in Page layouts.